# debug_backtrace() missing late bindings of class name

Tags: php, debug-backtrace

Suppose this scenario:

> class B extend class A and there is a method "myMethod" defined in
>   class A.

Inside `myMethod` I need to know the method name

Using

`__METHOD__`
always return the "className::" part referred to A `A::myMethod`

My solution is:

`static::class."::".__FUNCTION__`

In this way return the class reference to current working class

`B::methodName`

This work like a charm. But what if I need it in debug_backtrace()?

In debug_backtrace the [class] always refers to class A (accordingly with example provided)

How to obtain a correct binding in debug_backtrace?